# Making recommendation based on the hotel location

Tags: php, mysql

I am wanting to making a recommendation for the user that is based on the hotel's location. The code below is making recommendation to the user every time they rate, it gives the user hotels that they haven't rated yet (based on Euclidean  similarity distance). However, it doesn't into account the location of the hotel. So I want to implement an sql statement after generating the recommendation that would get the same location that the user has rated.

```
        <?php
        $hotel_count = 0;
        if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
            if(rated($_SESSION['user_id'])){

        $hotels = array();
        $hotels = getUsersHotels();
        $re = new Recommend();
        $recommendations =   ($re->getRecommendations($hotels,$_SESSION['user_name'])); 
        $hotel_names = array_keys($recommendations);
        $hotel_ratings = array_values($recommendations);
        $hotel_count = count($hotel_names);

        }
        }
```

DB for hotel structure:

```
id(int 11) 
Hotel_name(text)
Hotel_Location(text)
Hotel_price(int 11) 
image(varchar 500) 
description(text)
```

DB for rating structure:

```
id(int 11) 
rate(float) 
user_id(int 11)
hotel_id(int 11)
time_date(datetime)
```

Comment: "*based on Euclidean similarity distance*" - Distance from what, if it "doesn't into account the location of the hotel"?

Comment: Also, what are you recommending the hotels for? For the people to rate them, or for the people to book at the hotels?

Comment: @Mike The recommendation is done when the recommendation is done by the user. And the distance is from the other users